# geoJSON does not render

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to show a large set feature set of geoJSON comprising of points (around 3000 of them). However it's not working and I dont see anything when I try to add it to map. I am using Leaflet JS. I even tried it on geojson.io but the points appear outside the map.

It seems to me that the geoJSON format is not correct which I'm using.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [1.25147, 103.833183]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": "J_3767",
                "type": "junction"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [1.267052, 103.817162]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": "J_3764",
                "type": "junction"
            }
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a valid portion the data? Where di you expect the points to be located? How does the the code consuming the data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a named CRS (coordinate reference system) in this GeoJSON dataset? If not, a coordinate pair defaults to [longitude, latitude] in the WGS84 datum. Your latitude values are larger than 90, which is impossible. So either you have latitudes and longitudes reversed, or are measuring angles a non-standard way, or you're using a different coordinate system.

Where are these points supposed to be located? I'd check the actual lat/long values (note that the order in GeoJSON is the other way round -- x-coordinate first, then y-coordinate).

Comment: Thats the correct answer. Thankyou. I had the long/lats in reverse order.